# How to run parent body while loading child class?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have these methods where at the time of loading class `T` calls `methodA` but I want to alter this behaviour, I want it to be called when child class of `T` (eg `T2`) is being called without touching child classes.

```
def methodA
   puts "method has been called"
end
Class T
   method A
   def methodB
   end
end

Class T2 < T
end
```

I have tried using this code:

```
class T
   if self.superclass ==T
      methodA
   end
end
```

but it won't solve my problem because it does not run this body when child is being loaded.

Is there any way I can do that? If yes, then please let me know how!

Comment: There's an [`inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback, maybe that helps.

Comment: Here is a list of Metaprogramming related hooks - http://codefol.io/posts/What-Hooks-does-Ruby-have-for-Metaprogramming   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127819/is-this-a-comprehensive-list-of-ruby-hook-methods

Comment: @Stefan is a master of understatement.

Comment: @Stefan, actually I wanted to do the other way, but I could solve my problem with this. Would you mind posting it as an answer? Then I could accept that. Since you commented first,  I think I should accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `inherited` callback, that will be executed when it loads the child class and will be executed as soon as it loads child class `T2`. Sample code like below -

```
def methodA
  puts "method has been called"
end


class T
   def self.inherited(subclass)
     methodA   
   end
end
```